# how to combine multiple data into a single row

Tags: mysql

i have a problem on using the SELECT sql function.i am trying to get a data from my table such as following:

```
 cid    | cname   | fid | fname          | type   | status  | 
 10     | sue     | 4   | Bun            | pickup | pending | 
 10     | sue     | 10  | Lamb           | pickup | pending | 
 10     | sue     | 17  | Cheese         | pickup | pending | 
 10     | sue     | 31  | Spicy          | pickup | pending | 
 12     | lho     | 5   | crispy bun     | pickup | pending | 
 12     | lho     | 8   | Chicken        | pickup | pending | 
 12     | lho     | 17  | Cheese         | pickup | pending | 
 12     | lho     | 29  | Normal         | pickup | pending |
```

i was trying to make it like this:

```
 cid   | cname   | fname                               | type   | status  |
 10    | sue     | Bun, Lamb, Cheese, Spicy            | pickup | pending |
 12    | lho     | Crispy bun, Chicken, Cheese, Normal | pickup | pending |
```

below is my query:

```
$query="SELECT cid, cname, cnumber, type, date, fid, status, fname,
GROUP_CONCAT(fname SEPARATOR ', ') FROM purchase GROUP BY cname,cid";
```

are there any solution to my problem?please help and thanks you so much.

Comment: what results are you getting when you run your query?

Comment: I guess you have random values in `fid, type, status, etc ...` because when you `GROUP BY` you should set fields in `GROUP BY` statement, or use aggregate function such as `MIN, MAX, AVG, GROUP_CONCAT` otherwise the result is random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT` already adds the `commas` for you, no need to add them, see below:

```
$query="SELECT cid, cname, cnumber, type, date, fid, status,
GROUP_CONCAT(fname) FROM purchase GROUP BY cname,cid";
```

Comment: thanks andre3wap..it does work..i just add after the (fname) as result then it pop out just the way i want it to..thanks bro..thumbs up..

Comment: No problem, happy coding :)